# Multiple conditional formattings in script fails (and is ineffective code)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Been struggling to get conditional formatting to work. Trying to set background color of cell based on string in same cell. Would think it´s straightforward, but in my case I have a list of strings I want to look for.
In desperation for a solution I tried something that would almost work 100%.

I used a long sequence of these 2 almost identical code snips. Each code piece with a new string to search for.

```
var searchstring = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenTextContains("IF YOU FIND THIS STRING AS PART OF CELL - COLOR #f56970")
    .setBackground("#f56970")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(searchstring);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);

var searchstring = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenTextEqualTo("IF THIS IS THE TOTAL STRING OF CELL - COLOR #f56970")
    .setBackground("#f56970")
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(searchstring);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
```

...and several more of these code pieces adding new strings in whenTextContains & whenTextEqualTo.

There must be better ways to do this than this massive series of code snips. For starters I should probably put the main part as a function that is called with string as parameter.

**BUT...before I do that change for optimization, I want to know why this way of coding seems to stop halfway through the list of strings**. Is the sequence of several of these kind of code pieces making something fill up so that it just ignores some of the first pr last formatting requests?

Is there a better way to do this? I´m trying to do this programatically, but could go for the manual way of inserting rules into the sheet through menu. But then I would need a way to trigger the conditional formatting check after my script is ran, since it doesn´t seem to work for changes due to a script.

An example illustrating what I want to achieve.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GALq3DN0DQDBUdfFNQ1z1BWWa_q4oDWrVXJIZEztR04/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- About `stop halfway through the list of strings`, although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand it, I'm worried that if your `range` is the data range, when a new value is put into the outside of the current data range, the conditional format rule doesn't work. I thought that this might be your current issue.
- And, in your script, I think that when an object is used, the script might become simple.

If my understanding is correct and when these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script 1:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Ark 1"; // Please set your sheet name. This is from your sample.
  
  // This object is created from your expected result in your provided spreadsheet.
  // If you want to change your condition, please modify as follows.
  const obj = [
    { search: "STRING111", color: "#00ff00", rule: "whenTextContains" },
    { search: "STRING333", color: "#ff0000", rule: "whenTextContains" },
    { search: "THE WHOLE STRING", color: "#6d9eeb", rule: "whenTextEqualTo" },
  ];

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getMaxRows() - 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());
  sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules(); // If you want to update, please use this.
  const rules = obj.map(({ search, color, rule }) => SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()[rule](search).setBackground(color).setRanges([range]).build());
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
}
```

- When this script is run, the conditional format rules are installed using your expected condition. And, the range is the whole cells in the sheet. By this, even when you put a new value outside of the data range, the conditional format rule is used.
- If you want to use only the current data range as `range`, please modify `const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getMaxRows() - 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());` to `const range = sheet.getDataRange();`.
- If you want to use only column "A" as `range`, please modify `const range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getMaxRows() - 1, sheet.getMaxColumns());` to `const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A");`.
- As additional information, when you change the sheet size, please run the script again. By this, whole cells are used.

#### Modified script 2:

As another approach, in this modification, all cell values are checked, and set the background colors by running the script. When you run this script after you edited the cell, the background color of column "A" is set.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  const sheetName = "Ark 1"; // This is from your sample.
  const obj = [
    { search: "STRING111", color: "#00ff00", rule: "contains" },
    { search: "STRING333", color: "#ff0000", rule: "contains" },
    { search: "THE WHOLE STRING", color: "#6d9eeb", rule: "equal" },
  ];
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const values = range.getDisplayValues().map(r => r.map(c => {
    const s = obj.find(({ search, rule }) => {
      if (rule == "contains") {
        return c.includes(search);
      } else if (rule == "equal") {
        return search == c;
      }
      return false;
    });
    return s ? s.color : null;
  }));
  range.setBackgrounds(values);
}
```

- If you want to use the data range, please modify `sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());` to `sheet.getDataRange();`.
- For example, when `myFunctio2` is modified to `onEdit`, when the cell is edited, the script is automatically run.

#### Note:

- In this script, for example, if the values of `STRING111` and `STRING333` are put into a cell, `#00ff00` is used. If you want to use `#ff0000` at this time, please replace the 1st and 2nd element of `obj`.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setConditionalFormatRules(rules)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setconditionalformatrulesrules)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I´ll look into it. I failed to say that the number of text/content-elements I want to match (or partially match) can be in the region of 10-20 (Not just these 3 examples). So my question is how much "const obj" can hold? I couldn´t really find a good answer in documentation.

Comment: @Ola Dunk Thank you for replying. I proposed 2 patterns because I cannot know your actual situation. So, when you use 10 - 20 conditions in my 1st script and the process is a bit slow, please try to use my 2nd script. In that case, all colors are reflected in the cells by one call. So, the process cost will become low.

Comment: OK. Thanks! the speed isn't really that important though, since it's a one-time job. My script is merging several bank and credit card statements from individual excel exports, arranging them in matching columns, merging all into one sheet and list by date. So I end up in one view where all transactions are in one sheet.

Comment: @Ola Dunk Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I couldn't understand your current issue with my proposed answer. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue using my proposed scripts? If my answer has the issue for your question, I have to modify it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. "Modified script 1" works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const sA = [["String1","red"],["String2","yellow"],["String3","blue"]];
  sA.forEach((r,i) => {
    sh.createTextFinder(r[0]).findAll().forEach(rg => rg.setBackground(sA[i][1]))
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! As I´ve stated in my answer to the reply above I need to use more than those 3 matches I included in my answer. So the question would be how many elements I can fill in the "const sA" square brackets?